Period Retrieval from Natural Language
Have a certain requirement, there are user queries from where we need to find the right period.. e.g.
Show income QoQ "Output expected": period in ('Q3-2024','Q2-2024')
Total revenue as of last month "Output expected": period in ('Jul-2024')
Income for Q3 "Output expected": period in ('Q3-2024')
PTD Cost of Goods Sold (PTD means Period till date) "Output expected": period in ('Q1-2024','Q2-2024','Q3-2024') (lets say Aug is in current Quarter 3 for this year) hence all period from Jan till date is considered.
.......... and this can list go and user type any queries like this.
We have a pre-defined period meaning which year from which date to date, that corresponds to which quarter, or which month in that period year.That means which date corresponds to which month(e.g. Jul-2024), corresponds to which quarter (e.g. Q3-2024), in which year (e.g. 2024)
If the period is pre-defined, how do I fetch the necessary date part from the complete text, and then use that mapped to a period defined and get the result.
"2024": {
    "Qtr1-2024": {
        "Jan-24": {
            "start": "01/01/2024",
            "end": "31/01/2024"
        }, 
        "Feb-24": {
            "start": "01/02/2024",
            "end": "28/02/2024"
        },
        "Mar-24": {
            "start": "01/03/2024",
            "end": "31/03/2024"
        },
    },
    "Qtr2-2024": {
        "Apr-24": {
            "start": "01/04/2024",
            "end": "30/04/2024"
        }, 
        "May-24": {
            "start": "01/05/2024",
            "end": "31/05/2024"
        },
        "Jun-24": {
            "start": "01/06/2024", 
            "end": "30/06/2024"
        }            
    },
    "Qtr3-2024": {
        "Jul-24": {
            "start": "01/07/2024", 
            "end": "31/07/2024",
        },
        "Aug-24": {
            "start": "01/08/2024", 
            "end": "31/08/2024"
        },
        "Sep-24": {
            "start": "01/09/2024",
            "end": "30/09/2024"
        }            
    },
    "Qtr4-2024": {
        "Oct-24": {
            "start": "01/10/2024",
            "end": "31/10/2024"
        }, 
        "Nov-24": {
            "start": "01/11/2024", 
            "end": "30/11/2024"
        },
        "Dec-24": {
            "start": "01/12/2024",
            "end": "31/12/2024"
        }            
    }
}


LLM would be an overkill here, possibly
